# Difficult in understanding Interthread Communication

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

Can anyone explain this program on inter-thread communication?

// A correct implementation of a producer and consumer.

```
class Q {
    int n;
    boolean valueSet = false;
    synchronized int get() {
        while(!valueSet)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
        System.out.println("Got: " + n);
        valueSet = false;
        notify();
        return n;
    }
    synchronized void put(int n) {
        while(valueSet)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
        this.n = n;
        valueSet = true;
        System.out.println("Put: " + n);
        notify();
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
    Q q;

    Producer(Q q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Producer").start();
    }
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while(true) {
            q.put(i++);
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Q q;
    Consumer(Q q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Consumer").start();
    }
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            q.get();
        }
    }
}

class PCFixed {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Q q = new Q();
        new Producer(q);
        new Consumer(q);
        System.out.println("Press Control-C to stop.");
    }
}
```

Output

Put: 1
Got: 1
Put: 2
Got: 2
Put: 3
Got: 3
Put: 4
Got: 4
......

It is very confusing as far as I am concerned, especially the put and get methods where notify() and wait() are used. Please also explain why a boolean value is used.

Comment: @NathanHughes i am sorry & really embarassed to be a noob but can u help me out i am really poor in programming skills

Comment: i just meant it's better to be clearer about what exactly you don't understand. otherwise we don't know what to address.

Comment: can't understand y my questions are voted down.is it a sin to ask doubts in stackoverflow.i think if i ask one or two questions more i won't even have reputation to comment or vote up an answer....grrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are 2 threads. Qne is setting values on this Q data structure and the other is reading them. Q uses a boolean flag to tell whether a new value is present, the flag gets cleared once an existing value is read.

Q.get uses wait to block until a new value is available to read. Once it's read the new value it sets the flag back to false.

Q.put waits until the other queue has read the new value before setting it to a new value, then lets the other thread know by setting the boolean flag and calling notify.

Remember that wait gives up the lock so the other thread can acquire it.

The boolean flag is needed because a thread may stop waiting without having been notified. Just because a thread woke up doesn't mean it got a notification. Also, even if the thread gets notified, since the thread gave up the lock when it started to wait, the current state of things is unknown (in general there are multithreaded programs where another thread might sneak in and snag something between the time a thread is notified and the time it can regain the lock) so the thread has to re-test the condition again once it has the lock.

Constructs like wait and notify are building blocks for large concurrent programs, so some things may not make as much sense in a small example with only two threads.

Comment: because the producer and consumer shouldn't have order dependencies, you don't want to require having to call one or the other first.

Comment: but there should be a order right!! i mean if producer does not put anything into queue what is there for the consumer to get so shouldn't producer be called first..

Comment: the Q shouldn't insist on an order. otherwise you would have a race condition where if the wrong thread got there first it would be broken. as it is, if the consumer gets there first, it gives up the lock and waits to be notified.

Comment: i  am referring the code from herbert schildt's java book. it says that race condition occurs when two threads call the same method @ the same time but here two threads are accessing two different methods @ same  time. moreover the  other guy who answered my question(in comment section) says that there should be a order.so can u clear the confusion

Comment: your definition is too narrow, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition. the jvm spec does not guarantee which thread will start and get picked by the scheduler to execute first.

Answer (score 1):

See basically its a multithreaded communication with synchronized methods.

simple rquirement here is

1)first allow to write for producer.

2)next allow to read for consumer.

that  is controlled using boolean flag `valueSet`.

in case of producer means put method of Q, logic works this way
if the `valueSet` is is `true` means already write is done then ask put method called thread to wait. so it goes to wait until someone calls notify.

ofcourse it wont continue further logic and keeps on waiting for someone to call notify.

coming to reader means get() of Q,

if the `valueSet` is is `false` means  writter is executing  then ask get method called thread to wait. so it goes to wait until someone calls notify.

so once writer completes the execution it calls notify at the end and now reader threads awake and starts reading.

Comment: Thanks ..now on your question -> valueSet variable is default initialized to false because while(valueSet) inside put method has to fail so that producer thread wont go to wait initially, because first we should allow producer to produce the data instead of making it to wait. and once its done writing put method end we set valueSet to true and then call notify() if you observe carefully which makes reader to wake up and use the valueSet true value which causes it to bypass while because while(!valeSet) and allows to read ..like that it keeps on going..any doubts ?